# Cerrar modal que utiliza su propio controlador - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Buenas tardes,

Usando AngularJS 1.6:

Tengo una vista Login.html que en determinado momento, lanza un pop-up llamado 'modalAuthorization'. Esta modal tiene su propio controlador (independiente de loginController).

La modal tiene 2 botones, aceptar y rechazar, si hago click sobre alguno de ellos, se llamará (lógicamente) a métodos del controlador 'modalAuthorizationController', al finalizar la lógica de estas acciones, quiero que se cierre la modal pero no lo consigo.

Si la modal estuviese contenida en el controlador del Login sería más sencillo ( un close() o un $scope.modal = false) pero por una serie de motivos tengo que hacerlo así.

En resumidas cuentas tendría que hacer por así decirlo un 'close-myself'

```
app.controller('authorizationCtrl', ['$scope', 'AppService_Ajax', 'urlsRest', 'gettextCatalog', 'AppService_PersistData', 'AppService_Mensajes', function ($scope, AppService_Ajax, urlsRest, gettextCatalog, AppService_PersistData, AppService_Mensajes) {

  $scope.urlAuthorization = urlsRest.urlRestGeneral + '/addEntityParameter';


  $scope.rejectAuthorization = function () {
    var obj = {
        'idParametro': 25,
        'codValor': '0'
    }

    AppService_Ajax.sync($scope.urlAuthorization, 'POST', obj, function (res) {
        if (res.code == 0) {
            //HERE THE CLOSE METHOD
        }
    }
    );

    $scope.close();
    $state.go('app.administrador');
}
}]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consideraste usar `ui.bootstrap`? Este componente tiene entre otras funcionalidades la de generar un `popup (modal)` muy fácil de implementar

Comment: El problema es que es una parte puntual de un proyecto muy grande por eso me limita tanto.